# How to see disk details like manufacturer in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-disk, sfdisk

With `sfdisk -s` I can see the disk capacity as follows:

```
$ sfdisk -s
/dev/cciss/c0d0: 143338560
total: 143338560 blocks
```

How do I see disk details like disk manufacturer? I tried `hdparm`, but got an error:

```
$ hdparm -i  /dev/cciss/c0d0
/dev/cciss/c0d0:
HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/609708/how-to-find-hard-drive-brand-name-or-model

Answer (score 105):

Try these commands:

```
lshw -class disk  

hwinfo --disk
```

You may have to install `hwinfo`.

Concerning `hdparm`:
hdparm(8) says:

```
Although this utility is intended primarily for use with SATA/IDE hard disk 
devices, several of the options are also valid (and permitted) for use with 
SCSI hard disk devices and MFM/RLL hard disks with XT interfaces.
```

and:

```
Some options (eg. -r for SCSI) may not work with old kernels as necessary 
ioctl()´s were not supported.
```

Comment: the command hwinfo & lshw are not installed in my linux

Comment: can you provide some more information about your system?

Comment: @jennifer: Install at least one of them! All the information they return is available elsewhere, but they have the advantage of *collecting* all that information from many different places.

Comment: Running the command `lshw -class disk` as a regular user does not display information on disk (Ubuntu 15.04). Hopefully the bottom printed line says *"WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user."* Running again using `sudo` fixes the issue :-)

Comment: I wonder why `lshw` simply did not show my SSD: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/how-to-see-disk-details-like-manufacturer-in-linux/490819#490819

Comment: The name `/dev/cciss/c0d0` indicates the OP's system uses a HP SmartArray hardware RAID controller, and so any "disk" shown by it is actually a RAID set, which may or may not correspond directly to any single physical disk. In that specific situation, you'll need a tool that knows how to talk to the RAID controller and get the information on actual physical drives from it. `hwinfo`, `lshw` or `smartctl` mentioned in other answers all understand some types of hardware RAID controllers; a vendor-specific RAID management tool will usually get the most information.

Comment: `lshw` didn't show the manufacturer for me, but `hwinfo` did.

Answer (score 68):

You could read the disk properties directly through sysfs, also check the other files/dirs in */sys/class/block/**sda**/device/* (replace **sda** with drive you need).

```
cat /sys/class/block/sda/device/{model,vendor}
```

Comment: I dont have block directory

Comment: Use a recent kernel maybe, what distro are you using? try `dmesg | less`, should see the disks get probed.

Comment: @jennifer: `cat /sys/block/sd?/device/{model,vendor}` (`/sys/class/block` only appeared fairly recently, and your distribution is a little old).

Answer (score 23):

## lsblk (List Block)

You can use `lsblk` command:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL

NAME        FSTYPE LABEL   MOUNTPOINT                      SIZE MODEL
...
nvme0n1                                                  119.2G TS128GMTE110S                           
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat           /boot/efi                       512M 
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4           /                             118.8G
```

Perfectly informed, my NVMe SSD is a **Transced 110S 128GB** (TS128GMTE110S)

Comment: +1 This provides nice output and does not require root access!

Comment: You can add the model name to the default output of lsblk with `lsblk -o +model`, that's even easier!

Comment: This is a nice tip, and I almost updated the answer. But I realize that the default output also misses other fields and, for informational purposes, I suggest to leave the answer as it is.

Answer (score 18):

try running `smartctl -a /dev/hda` (could be sda in your case; `cat /proc/partitions` will show you the device type to use)

In your case it's behind a cciss controller, so the option should be `-d cciss,0` or similar.

Answer (score 9):

I know these answers are 3 years old, but for anyone looking around...
In older versions you could find that under (`?` should be a number):

```
/sys/class/scsi_device/?:?:?:?/device/model
```

by doing this:

```
cat /sys/class/scsi_device/0\:0\:0\:0/device/{model,vendor}
```

(The backslashes next to zeros are for escaping special char `:`.)

Answer (score 5):

### `lsblk` (List blocks) gives a list with device, size, type and mount_point

```
sudo lsblk 
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0  465.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1                   8:1    0  465.8G  0 part /data
sdb                      8:16   0    1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1                   8:17   0 1002.3G  0 part 
│ └─lvmvolumeSda6-home 254:0    0    2.8T  0 lvm  /home
└─sdb2                   8:18   0  860.7G  0 part 
sdc                      8:32   0  232.9G  0 disk 
└─sdc1                   8:33   0  232.9G  0 part 
sdd                      8:48   1    3.7T  0 disk 
└─sdd1                   8:49   1    3.7T  0 part /mnt/backups
sde                      8:64   1    1.8T  0 disk 
├─sde1                   8:65   1  864.5G  0 part 
│ └─lvmvolumeSda6-home 254:0    0    2.8T  0 lvm  /home
└─sde2                   8:66   1  998.6G  0 part 
  └─lvmvolumeSda6-home 254:0    0    2.8T  0 lvm  /home
sr0                     11:0    1   1024M  0 rom  
sr1                     11:1    1   1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1                259:0    0  465.8G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0  134.8G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0    1.9G  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p3            259:3    0      1K  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4            259:4    0     87G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p5            259:5    0     15G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p6            259:6    0  227.2G  0 part /data_nvme
```

### `lsblk -S` gives model, vendor, etc...

```
sudo lsblk -S
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL             REV TRAN
sda  0:0:0:0    disk ATA      WDC WDS500G1B0A- 10WD sata
sdb  1:0:0:0    disk ATA      WDC WD20EFRX-68E 0A82 sata
sdc  5:0:0:0    disk ATA      Samsung SSD 850  1B6Q sata
sdd  10:0:0:0   disk ATA      WDC WD40EFRX-68W 0A82 sata
sde  11:1:0:0   disk ATA      WDC WD20EARS-00M AB51 sata
sr0  9:0:0:0    rom  ASUS     BC-12D2HT        1.00 sata
sr1  11:0:0:0   rom  TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB  SB00 sata
```

Answer (score 3):

**`gnome-disks`**

Either `gnome-disks` or just "Disks" on the Ubuntu 18.10 dash:

[image]

This shows that I have a [SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-000L7](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/ssd/client-ssd/MZVLB512HAJQ/) in my Lenovo ThinkPad P51.

TODO why: for some reason, my SSD model was not showing clearly on either of:

```
sudo lshw -class disk
sudo hwinfo --disk
```

- `lshw` did not how the SSD at all, only my hard disk
- `hwinfo` did show both, but for the SSD said just:

  ```
  Model: "Samsung Electronics Disk"
  ```

  while for the HD it contains the actual model...

  ```
  Model: "ST1000LM035-1RK1"
  ```

This one from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5087/32558 worked though:

```
cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/device/model
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this command as root user.

```
hpacucli ctrl all show config detail
```

Comment: this is a command specific to hp raid controllers - so it is not useful here

Answer (score -2):

The `lssd` command can also help you.

Comment: Can you provide some sample output or an explanation of where to find this tool? It's not available in my Fedora 20 system, for example.

Comment: @slm That is part of the fibreutils package that originates/d from HP.

Comment: @Anthon - so then it's not a standard linux package?

Comment: @slm I'm pretty sure I have it from the RedHat machines I used to have access to. It is a bash script, but I haven't used it for many years. It calls `scsi_info` which I don't have on my Ubuntu system at all.

Comment: @slm correction, I have the source for scsi_info, comes with the RPM. Just not compiled/installed.

Comment: @Anthon - I just searched the F20 repos that I have access to for `lssd` & `scsi_info` and neither returned a hit. Here `lssd` is mentioned w/ fibreutils as you described: ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib2/software1/doc/p603757071/v60944/psp-8.41.rhel5.linux.txt

Comment: @slm I didn't install the original system, just found & used the util (I have an unused fibrechannel board somewhere). http://www.filewatcher.com/m/fibreutils-2.5-4.x86_64.rpm.56725-0.html

Comment: I'm thinking this Q is missing a tag. I'm not that familiar with fibrechannel, seems like it's related to that.